# Can I make combobox which will filter range for 2nd combobox?

Tags: excel, vba

Lets say i have database with books in storage and i have 1 book at 3 places. I need to pick a book from place using userform like this
[userform](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VghzX.png)

and i need to use first combobox to filter name of book and then the 2nd will show placement of filtered book. Then the commandbutton will work with that book at chosen placemet.

Comment: The sounds fine.  What's the exact problem you're having with this?  Where are you stuck?

Answer (score 1):

Create a new onevent procedure, such as `Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()`, and use that to update `ComboBox2` based on the the current value of `ComboBox1`.

Answer (score 0):

to add to pheeper's response you can do something like this

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()
Select Case ComboBox1.Value
    Case "Book1"
        ComboBox2.RowSource = "List1"
    Case "Book2"
        ComboBox2.RowSource = "List2"
    Case Else
        ComboBox2.RowSource = "MainList"
End Select
End Sub
```